# Code using arrays to determine reaction times, says I cannot convert double to double[] wondering how to fix it

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just beginning off and have to implement code that uses an array to take the reaction times and 
  average them out in the end. The comments in the code are instructions for the assignment. I know some parts are messy and my coding isn't the best so I'm willing to other suggestions you all may have on how to further my work.

```
import java.util.*;
public class reactionTimes
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    // 1. Create a Scanner object called scan.
   Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    // 2. Declare and initialize an array called times of size 10 that contains all doubles.
    //    Don't set any values yet.
   double[] times = new double[10];

    // 3. Create a for loop that will fill times with values.
    //    Each time the for loop is iterated, ask the user for their reaction time
   for (int count = 0; count <= 10; count++)
     System.out.print(count + 1 + ") Reaction time:");
     times = scan.nextDouble();

    // 4. Create a double variable called average that contains the average reaction time of the user.
    //    You can do this with lots of typing or by using a for loop: your choice!
   double average;

   average = (times[0] + times[1] + times[2] + times[3] + times[4] + times[5] + times[6] + times[7] + times[8] + times[9] + times[10]) / 10; 

    // 5. Print a message stating the average reaction time of the user.
   System.out.println("The average reaction time is " + average);

    // 6. If the user had an average less than 0.2, print a congratulatory message.
    //    Otherwise, tell the user to practice more.
   if (average <= 0.2)
     System.out.print(" , good job! You're very quick.");
   else
     System.out.print(" , you need to practice more.");
  }
}
```

Comment: You should really point in your question that the problem is raised at line `times = scan.nextDouble();`

Comment: You have to say times[count]=scan.nextDouble() to specify the index.

For number 3, you need to have braces around both statements in order to include them both in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign to an array, you must use array access, with the loop.  Also use braces for the loop.

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)  // Changed <= to < and added braces
{
   System.out.print(count + 1 + ") Reaction time:");
   times[count] = scan.nextDouble();  // times changed to times[count]
}
```